# How do I add a column to a dataframe whose name and value is a function of other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I would like to add a series of columns to a dataframe, whose names and values are a function of other columns in the same row. Consider the example below, where I add a column 1997q1 (i.e. the first quarter of 1997) whose values are the sum of the first three months of 1997 data. This is easy enough to accomplish on its own, however I would like to create a new column for every quarter over a period of many years.

For example if I start with the dataframe:

[image]

I would like to end with the following dataframe (the 1997-xx columns are included but they have to be deleted):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`df.sum()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
df['q1'] = df[['1997-01', '1997-02', '1997-03']].sum(axis=1)

df
Out[66]: 
          RegionName     State   1997-01   1997-02   1997-03        q1
0 New           York        NY       NaN       NaN       NaN       0.0
1 Los        Angeles        CA  155900.0  157000.0  157700.0  470600.0
2 Chicago         IL  110800.0  111300.0  111700.0       NaN  223000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have the following DF:

```
In [323]: df
Out[323]:
    RegionName State  1997-01  1997-02  1997-03  1997-04  1997-11
0     New York    NY      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
1  Los Angeles    CA      1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0
2      Chicago    IL      2.0      2.0      2.0      2.0      2.0
```

let's first extract only `date` columns:

```
In [324]: x = df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r'\d{4}\-\d{2}')]]

In [325]: x
Out[325]:
   1997-01  1997-02  1997-03  1997-04  1997-11
0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
1      1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0
2      2.0      2.0      2.0      2.0      2.0
```

now we can group by [PeriodIndex(..., freq='Q'))](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#periodindex-and-period-range)

```
In [326]: new = x.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(x.columns, freq='Q'), axis=1).sum()

In [327]: new
Out[327]:
   1997Q1  1997Q2  1997Q4
0     NaN     NaN     NaN
1     3.0     1.0     1.0
2     6.0     2.0     2.0
```

finally we can join it with the original DF:

```
In [328]: df.join(new)
Out[328]:
    RegionName State  1997-01  1997-02  1997-03  1997-04  1997-11  1997Q1  1997Q2  1997Q4
0     New York    NY      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1  Los Angeles    CA      1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0     3.0     1.0     1.0
2      Chicago    IL      2.0      2.0      2.0      2.0      2.0     6.0     2.0     2.0
```